# SQL Server : merge statement error

Tags: sql-server, merge

Could any one let me know what was the issue here in this merge statement.

```
MERGE table_inventory as TARGET 
USING temp_table_inventory as SOURCE ON (TARGET.sku_code = SOURCE.sku_code) 

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT (sku_code, inventory) 
    VALUES (SOURCE.sku_code, SOURCE.inventory) 

WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET TARGET.inventory = SOURCE.inventory ;
```

I am getting an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Thanks
Basu

---

Could anyone suggest me a sample sql to insert or update based on a join for the above query with out using merge.

Appreciate your response.

Comment: The code you have there looks good - is there any code surrounding it?  Have you tried running the above on its own / with no surrounding statements?

Comment: Appreciate your quick response. I am just running this query. No code surrounding.

Answer (score 1):

`SOURCE` is a keyword used in [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx). i.e. `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE`.

The error is in this line

```
USING temp_table_inventory as SOURCE
```

Change the name to `Src`